# After heroku deploy css isn't aplied

Tags: javascript, css, heroku, mern

I just finished my project and deployed it to heroku.
everything works great except that I am using MUI and I used to override their css in my index.css like this :

```
.css-yuzg60-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiPaginationItem-root.Mui-selected {
  background-color: var(--clr-mocha-2) !important;
  color: white;
}

.css-yuzg60-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiPaginationItem-root:hover {
  background-color: var(--clr-mocha-3) !important;
}
.css-1yk1gt9-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root-MuiSelect-root.Mui-focused
  .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: var(--clr-mocha-2) !important;
}

.css-1poimk-MuiPaper-root-MuiMenu-paper-MuiPaper-root-MuiPopover-paper {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

These lines of codes are not applied after deploy.. (It was working great before the deploy.)
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MUI is generated class names randomally each time I ran my app.

sx prop solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).